# Node.js Function Called Twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which is returning an array that calculates sales and purchase of json data.

When called it logs out the values, but the values are logged out twice resulting in loss of actual data because the loop isn't completed twice.

The function is as below:

```
async function GetTotalShareHeldForUserMarketGraph(data, name) {
    let current_data_now = new Date();
    let lastDateBackMonths = [];
    lastDateBackMonths.push(formatDateToString(current_data_now));
    let doi = 0;

    do {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() - doi + 1, 0);
        lastDateBackMonths.push(formatDateToString(d));
        doi++;
    } while (doi < 7);

    let pur_qnt_current = pur_qnt1 = pur_qnt2 = pur_qnt3 = pur_qnt4 = pur_qnt5 = pur_qnt6 = pur_qnt7 = 0;
    let sal_qnt_current = (sal_qnt1 = sal_qnt2 = sal_qnt3 = sal_qnt4 = sal_qnt5 = sal_qnt6 = sal_qnt7 = 0);
    let backMonthShareHeld_With_Current_share_held = [];
    let backMonthShareHeld = [];
    let current_price;

    data.forEach((v) => {
        let date = formatDateToString(v.Date);
        let time = formatTimeToString(v.Date);
        if (v["Details"] === name) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt_current += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt_current += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }
        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[0])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt1 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
                console.log("PURE1: " + pur_qnt1)
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt1 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }

        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[1])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt2 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt2 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }

        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[2])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt3 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt3 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }

        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[3])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt4 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt4 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }

        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[4])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt5 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt5 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }

        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[5])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt6 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt6 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }

        if (v["Details"] === name && formatDateToStringSlash(date) <= formatDateToStringSlash(lastDateBackMonths[6])) {
            if (
                v["Action"] === "PURCHASE" ||
                v["Action"] === "Matched Bid" ||
                v["Action"] === "Partially Matched Bid"
            ) {
                pur_qnt7 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
            if (v["Action"] === "SALE") {
                sal_qnt7 += GetTrueQuantity(date, time, v["Quantity"]);
            }
        }
    });

    current_price = await returnCurrentPrice(name);

    console.log(
        sal_qnt1,
        sal_qnt2,
        sal_qnt3,
        sal_qnt4,
        sal_qnt5,
        sal_qnt6,
        sal_qnt7
    );
    console.log(
        pur_qnt1,
        pur_qnt2,
        pur_qnt3,
        pur_qnt4,
        pur_qnt5,
        pur_qnt6,
        pur_qnt7
    );

    for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        var pur_qnt = "pur_qnt" + i;
        var sal_qnt = "sal_qnt" + i;
        console.log(eval(pur_qnt))
        var share_value = parseInt(eval(pur_qnt) - eval(sal_qnt));
        backMonthShareHeld[lastDateBackMonths[i - 1]] = share_value * current_price[0]["current_price"];
    }

    backMonthShareHeld_With_Current_share_held["current_held"] =
        parseInt(pur_qnt_current) - parseInt(sal_qnt_current);
    backMonthShareHeld_With_Current_share_held[
        "back_month_held"
    ] = backMonthShareHeld;
    return backMonthShareHeld_With_Current_share_held;
}
```

The console log looks like

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Then it runs again with output like

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Edit -
Input being given is

```
    portfolio_data.forEach(async (e) => {
        let true_date = formatDateToString(e.Date);
        let true_time = formatTimeToString(e.Date);

        if (first_transaction_date > true_date) {
            first_transaction_date = true_date;
        }

        user_data.push({
            user_id: userData[0].id,
            type: e.Action,
            name: e.Details,
            quantity: e.Quantity,
            total: e.Total || e.Value,
            date: new Date(),
        });

        let true_quantity = GetTrueQuantity(true_date, true_time, e.Quantity);

        if (total_share_held_back_months_values[e.Details]) {
            total_share_held_back_months =
                total_share_held_back_months_values[e.Details];
        } else {
            total_share_held_back_months = GetTotalShareHeldForUserMarketGraph(
                portfolio_data,
                e.Details
            );
            total_share_held_back_months_values[
                e.Details
            ] = total_share_held_back_months;
        }

        console.log(total_share_held_back_months)
        current_shares_held = total_share_held_back_months["current_held"];
        BackMonthShareHeldValues[e.Details] =
            total_share_held_back_months["back_month_held"];
```

Many thanks in advance as I can't seem to find the solution through docs or other issues!

Comment: Can you share sample inout you are trying?

Comment: @ShraavanHebbar Please see update to question

Comment: `portfolio_data.forEach(async (e) => {` is not designed to accept an `async` function.

Comment: "`total_share_held_back_months = GetTotalShareHeldForUserMarketGraph`" `GetTotalShareHeldForUserMarketGraph` is an async function and needs to be treated as such.